# Dice Roller using EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have the following code. I am trying to make a dice roller. However, the button doesn't seem to be functioning.  Any ideas what I am missing?  Is my EJS incorrect?

```
  <div class="dicecontainer">
    <div class="dice"><p id="rollresult">Result</p></div>

      <%  function roll() { %>
        <%  var result =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1); %> 
        <% document.getElementById("rollresult").innerHTML=result; %>
      <%  }; %>

     <button onclick="roll()">Roll Dice</button> 
 </div>
```

Comment: EJS is *server-side* JS, you're trying to write *client-side* code in there. (And I think your syntax is wrong for EJS anyway: I don't think you can dip in and out of EJS blocks in the middle of a statement)

Comment: Your answer in combination with the answer below solved the problem.   I had other EJS that was working fine in my code, but I didn't realize it was all server-side JS.    The script tags below solved the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you write javascript code inside ejs tags? It is by far more simple and easy to place your code inside `script` tag like this:

```
<div class="dicecontainer">
    <div class="dice"><p id="rollresult">Result</p></div>
     <button onclick="roll()">Roll Dice</button> 
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function roll() {
      var result =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
      document.getElementById("rollresult").innerHTML=result;
  };
</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.   Thanks!